# Click event listener is not triggered in test site but in stackoverflow code snippet

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I write a small JavaScript so that when user click a download link, then after 5 seconds, the current page will be redirected to a new "Thank you for downloading" page.

The test URL is at http://www.sybase-recovery.com/blogs/. I perform the test in Chrome DevTools, and add two breakpoints, as below:

[image]

during the test, breakpoint at 156 is already triggered, but the one at 157 is never triggered, even if I click the download item, see below:

[image]

I check DevTools and it does not report any error in JavaScript.

To test the issue, I copy the code snippet out and run in StackOverflow, but now the click event will be triggered again:

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      document.querySelector(".download-url").addEventListener("click", function () {
          var url = this.getAttribute('download-link');
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = url;
          }, 5000);
      });
    });
```

```html
    <ul class="sub-menu row-category-sub-menu">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-ds">
    <h5>
    MS Office File Recovery</h5>
    <li><a class="download-url" download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/access-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/download/daccr.exe" rel="preload"> Access Repair</a></li>
    <li><a class="download-url" download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/excel-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/download/dexcelr.exe" rel="preload"> Excel Repair</a></li>
    <li><a class="download-url" download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/word-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/download/dwordr.exe" rel="preload"> Word Repair</a></li>
    <li><a class="download-url" download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/powerpoint-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/download/dpptr.exe" rel="preload"> PowerPoint Recovery</a></li>
    </div>
    </div>
    </ul>
```

The new thank you page is not shown because security option that disable the page from displaying in a frame, but it is being loaded which means the click event is triggered.

So why in test site, the click event is not triggered?

Comment: You've setup event listener for the first link "Access Repair", it works when I visit your live site. No listeners attached for the rest of the download links.

Comment: @ProGu, Thank you very much. I only listen to the first element, not all the elements.